# Components in side-nav are not visible in app.component.html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created a code in the Models.ts file, thanks to this code, I need to call the headers in side-nav.component.ts to app.component.html, but when I want to call app.index.html by typing `<side-nav><side-nav>`, this component's says it's not specific

model.ts

```
export interface SideNavItem {
    title: string;
    link: string;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-page-header (menuClicked)="sideNav.toggle()"></app-page-header>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" #sideNav opened class="mat-elevation-z6">
    <side-nav></side-nav>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<app-page-footer></app-page-footer>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { PageHeaderComponent } from './page-header/page-header.component';
import { PageFooterComponent } from './page-footer/page-footer.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { SideNavComponent } from './side-nav/side-nav.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageHeaderComponent,
    PageFooterComponent,
    SideNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  
  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

side.nav.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SideNavItem } from '../models/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav',
  templateUrl: './side-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav.component.scss']
})
export class SideNavComponent {
  sideNavContent: SideNavItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Arabalar',
      link: 'cars/library',
    },
    {
      title: 'Arabaları Yönet',
      link: 'cars/maintenance',
    },
    {
      title: 'Kateogorileri Yöneti',
      link: 'cars/categories',
    },
    {
      title: 'Araç İade Et',
      link: 'cars/return',
    },
    {
      title: 'Kullanıcıları Gör',
      link: 'users/list',
    },
    {
      title: 'Bütün Siparişler',
      link: 'users/all-orders',
    },
    {
      title: 'Siparişlerim',
      link: 'users/order',
    },
  ]
}
```

side-nav.component.html

```
<mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let option of sideNavContent">
        {{option.title | titlecase}}
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

I tried  instead of  but it didn't worked.

I was getting errors when using  but not when using . But when using  the components I want are not called to the website.

[image][image][image]

Comment: `@Component({  selector: 'app-side-nav',`, so it's `<app-side-nav>`

Answer (score 0):

plz check component decorator

its `app-side-nav` not side-nav